# “Laitue” or “salade”?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

I have beginner French and was in France for a week. I noticed in sandwich bars that when choosing what to put on your sandwich people say *salade* when choosing lettuce. Does *salade* mean lettuce in this context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *laitue* is indeed a kind of *salade*, like the *mache*, *roquette*, *frisée*, *cresson*, *pissenlit*, *batavia*, *feuille de chêne*, *scarole*, *romaine*...

Like the English "salad", *salade* also means any seasoned (etymologically *salade* means "salted") mixture of food (vegetable, fruit, meat, seafood, cheese, whatever), usually eaten as a starter or for dessert if *salade de fruit*.

When there is a risk of confusion, we use *salade verte* to name the former, e.g.:

> *Il y a de la salade verte dans la salade.*

*Salade* can also be used colloquially to mean any inconsistent, confusing mixture of statements, lies:

> *Arrête de raconter des salades.* - Stop telling bullshit<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>***Salade*** is softer than "**bullshit**" though.</sub>

Comment: note that "des salades" is not as vulgar as "bullshit"

Comment: @AnneAunyme Yes, *salade* is softer but that was the closest English world that came to my mind.

Comment: @jlliagre What about "Stop talking rubbish" ?

Comment: @Derek Yes, rubbish is definitely less vulgar. It sounds very British in that acception, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, "salade" can mean "laitue".

"salade" is used to refer to either the raw vegetables themselves (lettuce, laitue), or to the seasoned dish prepared with such vegetables, or even to a dish mixing various ingredients that do not include lettuce, such as "salade de fruit".

"salade" can also be used figuratively to refer to a chaotic situation.